# Julia GraphDisplay error

Tags: compilation, package, julia

I am running an example and I receive this error.

**ERROR: LoadError: error compiling anonymous: unsupported or misplaced expression "using" in function anonymous
while loading /home/xxx/Desktop/xxx/TD1/exemple.jl, in expression starting on line 25**

These are lines 25 and 26 in the example,

> if GraphDisplay
>
> ```
> using Plots
> ```

I also get a warning

**WARNING: could not import Base.issymmetric into LinearOperators**

which goes away when I run Pkg.add("LinearOperators") but I have to do this everytime I quit and reopen Julia.

Comment: Can you provide more context (maybe the full `example.jl` if it's not too long)?

Comment: I didn't have the latest version of Julia installed. Upgrading to version 0.6.2 solved it.